# telegram bot - Bad Request: file must be non-empty

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to send a text file in [telegram bot](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot) for c# version 15.7.1 with the following code :

```
            var csvFile = new StringBuilder();
            foreach ( var person in persons)
            {
                var output = new List<string>
                {
                    person.Fardi.Name,
                    person.Fardi.LastName,
                    person.Fardi.PhoneNumber,
                    person.Fardi.BrithYear.ToString(),
                    person.Fardi.Father
                };
                csvFile.AppendLine(string.Join(_delimiter, output));
            }
            using var stream = new MemoryStream();
            using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            await streamWriter.WriteAsync(csvFile.ToString());
            await streamWriter.FlushAsync();
            await _botClient.SendDocumentAsync(new ChatId(chatId), new InputOnlineFile(stream, "test.txt"), replyMarkup: GetInlineKeyboard(buttons));
```

But when I send request, this error occurs :

```
Error while sending message
      Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.ApiRequestException: Bad Request: file must be non-empty
        at Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient.MakeRequestAsync[TResponse](IRequest`1 request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

But my stream isn't empty its length is 200.

Comment: `stream.Position = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what a *telegram bot* is, however the fix is likely as simple as rewinding the *stream* with [`MemoryStream.Position`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.position?view=net-5.0)

> Gets or sets the current position within the stream.

```
using var stream = new MemoryStream();
...
stream.Position = 0;
await _botClient.SendDocumentAsync(
    new ChatId(chatId), 
    new InputOnlineFile(stream, "test.txt"), 
    replyMarkup: GetInlineKeyboard(buttons));
```